# Socketio with angular and nodejs fails to connect

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, socket.io

I run node.js express server and try to connect a socket with angular.

This is my nodejs server:

```
import http from 'http';
import Debug from 'debug';

import socketio from 'socket.io';

import app from './app';

import ServerGlobal from './server-global';

const debug = Debug('node-angular');

const normalizePort = (val: string) => {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);

    if (isNaN(port)) {
        return val;
    }

    if (port >= 0) {
        return port;
    }

    return null;
};

const onError = (error: NodeJS.ErrnoException) => {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
    }

    const addr = server.address();
    const bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? ('pipe ' + addr) : ('port ' + port);

    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + 'requires elevated privileges');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
};

const onListening = () => {
    const addr = server.address();
    const bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? ('pipe ' + addr) : ('port ' + port);

    debug("Listening on " + bind);
};

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT);

app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new socketio.Server(server);

io.on('connection', () => console.log(33333))

server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
server.listen(port);

ServerGlobal.getInstance().logger.info(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
```

And this is my connection try in angular to the socket:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MainComponent } from './components/main/main.component';
import { UserListComponent } from './components/user-list/user-list.component';
import { UserDetailsComponent } from './components/user-details/user-details.component';

import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { HttpUserService } from './services/http/http-user.service';

const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3000', options: {} };

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainComponent,
    UserListComponent,
    UserDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
  ],
  providers: [
    UserService,
    HttpUserService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In my server socket declaration I did 'console.log()' once a socket is connected but I cant see it in my server console once I do connect in my angular application.

I can't find the problem - either in front -end of back-end

Comment: Open F12 DevTools and check whether there are some requests the browser is doing against http://localhost:3000 at all

Comment: @Yirkha Cannot see any.

Comment: Maybe `SocketIoModule` being imported does nothing by itself unless it's actually used somewhere, e.g. `private socket: Socket` in some other Angular service's constructor. Do you have something like that, how do you use the Socket? You can add that to the question.

Comment: Are you getting the prints that you added on the server-side as you expect? I am not sure that you shared here the right code for the front-end because you have nothing here to show the connection. I would recommend creating at least a service file on the angular app, in which you are going to connect to the socket on the same port as the server.